# Pervasive v10 ODBC install on Linux

Tags: unixodbc, pervasive

Can anyone tell me where I might be able to find the Pervasive v10 client for Linux? I need to install an UNIXODBC connection for Pervasive and need the client drivers. I have looked all over the Actian site and can only find the drivers for version 11 and up, but no version 10.

This is a brand new Linux install, so there were never Pervasive drivers previously installed. Also, if there is setup documentation for the driver on Linux.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual RPM / TAR for the client or instructions?  PSQL v10 went unsupported by Actian / Pervasive in Mar. 2012 ([https://supportservices.actian.com/support-services/support#lc_psql](https://supportservices.actian.com/support-services/support#lc_psql)).  If you don't have the Linix drivers, you might not be able to get them.  PSQL v10 is 3 major versions behind the current version.  You should upgrade to v13 to get supported versions.

Comment: Hi Mertheil, yes, I'm looking for the TAR archive if I can find it. You mention that I may not be able to get them because it's no longer supported. I'll see if upgrading is an option in the meantime. Thanks again, Mertheil.

Comment: If you have the PSQL v10 CD, you might have the TAR file.  I know Pervasive used to keep old versions available for download but I just checked and the oldest available is PSQL v11 SP3 (which has been unsupported since Jul 2016).

Comment: Thank you again, Mertheil. I'll have to look and see if we have the CD or not.